# Массив изображений Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, изображения

Есть ли возможность как-то создать массив изображений в Unity? Изображения генерируются во время работы программы, затем заносятся в массив.

Comment: Возможность имеется. Можете использовать `Image[]` или `List<Image>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Unity класс изображений - UnityEngine.UI.Image

1. Добавьте `using UnityEngine.UI.Image;`
2. Создайте `List<Image> images = new List<Image>();`
   Когда нужно будет добавить изображение просто напишите `images.Add({Твоё изображение});`
   Удалить можно так же `images.Remove({Твоё изображение});`